# Sent Stellar to the same wallet address

Tags: transactions

I have sent Stellar to the same Wallet address! will this go back into my Wallet account after some time. Or is there something I can do to retrieve it back?

Answer (score 0):

I tested a transaction on testnet using the stellar laboratory and it seems that if you send lumens to the same account it only deducts a fee - assuming the source account of the txn envelope is the same account on both sides of the payment operation. I actually expected the txn would fail but it did not. The lumens balance did not change except for the small amount for the fee.

Given this behavior, if your stellar balance decreased by more than the fee amount, you may have sent it to another address. Double check the transaction hash and make sure.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about that much. You will just get charged for very small amount fee of XLM (depending on the number of XLM you sent, but it's generally very low), and that's it.

Comment: I don't see what this adds to the existing answer.

Comment: @Chenmunka sorry about that.